# How do I attach an eventHandler for GridViewColumnHeader.Click with Caliburn Micro?

Tags: wpf, events, caliburn.micro, attached-properties

I have ListView with a GridView as the view which binds by convention to `Instances` property of my ViewModel:

```
<ListView Name="Instances">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property}"
                      Header="Property"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Now I need to trigger some method on the ViewModel when I click on a GridViewColumnHeader.

I tried this with enhancing the GridViewColumn like so

```
<ListView Name="Instances"
          cal:Message.Attach="[Event GridViewColumnHeader.Click] = [Action Foo()]">
  <!-- the rest stays unchanged -->
</ListView>
```

I even tried to play around with the ColumnHeaderContainerStyle like so

```
<GridView>
  <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
      <EventSetter Event="Click">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Foo"/>
        <!-- does not compile -->
      </EventSetter>
    </Style>
  </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

Which obviously did not work.

How can I connect a method (and not a command with a binding) from the ViewModel to an attached event (to ask in a more general way) with Caliburn Micro?

Comment: If I may, do you really have to do it through `VM`? I was creating sorting for my `ListView` with a `GridView` and just used the code-behind to sort. It saved a lot of time and hassle. This applies only if you need to do sorting. Your example looks like it's displaying some info after the sorting is done. This is just a suggestion HTH

Comment: @XAMlMAX absolutely, ... as I need to apply the propertyInfo (getting from the binding) to do a new query (with proper ordering) against the database as we only show an excerpt of the full dataset. otherwise sorting would simply be wrong...

Comment: ok, so how can you not use a simple `DrillDownCommand` to use in this situation? You can use the binding and pass the data to your method for the command and do exactly what you need to do. Unless I am missing some key constraint here? BTW `DrillDownCommand` would basically invoke your `Foo()` method.

Comment: @XAMlMAX could you possibly provide an example as an answer? I would like to add as less clutter as possible to stick to the Caliburn Micro practices as tight as possible.

Comment: no need, the answer is simpler then you think :-), replace your header template to use a button, then just Bind the right command from your VM and voila! :-) P.S. you'll have to style the button so it doesn't looks like one :-)

Comment: If my answer helped you solve the issue I would appreciate your acceptance of my answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: @XAMlMAX time is currently not on my side - I'll check later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by following @XAMIMAX suggestion:

```
<GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Button Content="{Binding}"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            Background="Transparent"
            cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Foo($this)]">
      <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Button.Template>
    </Button>
  </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate>
```

This triggers `Foo` on the ViewModel an passes the `{Binding}` (in my case: property-name) to it.

Comment: Do you know what else I thought of, I think the reason why your initial approach didn't work is because by default the template used for `GridViewColumnHeader` is `TextBlock` but to get that to work you would need to include `interaction` from Blend SDK to connect event and commands. HTH

Comment: @XAMlMAX do take this thinking a bit further: what is the actual sender of `GridViewColumnHeader.Click`? I believe that's the actual `GridViewColumnHeader`, and therefore there *should* be a way to attach to its click event...

Comment: I'll create an answer with all the details when I find some time. Bit busy at work at the moment.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the click will be triggered only if you click directly on the text. You need to stretch the button over the header by creating the ColumnHeaderContainerStyle like this:

    `<GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>  
        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">  
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>  
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>  
         </Style>  
     </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>`

Answer (score 1):

I have located [this](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Cheat%20Sheet) article explaining the calibrum a little bit, I have never used calibrum before so I had to do a bit of a research.
This is how the article presents the `Binding` in an alternative approach.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Name" />
<Button Content="Save"> 
    <i:Interaction.Triggers> 
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click"> 
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Save"> 
               <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=Name, Path=Text}" /> 
            </cal:ActionMessage> 
        </i:EventTrigger> 
    </i:Interaction.Triggers> 
</Button>
```

Where:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
```

In order for you to keep using the `TextBlock` in your application you would have to create an explicit definition of the `GridViewColumnHeader` like so:

```
<DataTemplate>
<!-- Without the Calibrum micro -->
    <TextBlock Text="Test">
       <TextBlock.InputBindings>
          <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}, Path=Text}"/>
       </TextBlock.InputBindings>
    </TextBlock>
<!-- With Calibrum Micro -->
    <TextBlock>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="LeftClick">
                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Save">
                    <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=Name, Path=Text}" /> 
                </cal:ActionMessage> 
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now this is just based on the material that I could gather from the internet and I am unable to test it as I am at work.
However this, if not working, should give you an idea of how to overcome some difficulties in your development.
EDIT:
And to answer your question:
Replace the `GridViewColumnHeader` `Template` with explicit definition of a `DataTemplate` and use a button so you can attach to the `Click` event, alternatively you could use `TextBlock` like in the example to avoid unnecessary overhead that comes with the use of a `Button`.
**EDIT**
After doing some research I can conclude that the usage of the methods on your View Model can be easy and fun :-).
Look at my working ListView:

```
<ListView>
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="TestPublicMethod" TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Example Header"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
<ListViewItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock>
            normal text with a lot of characters
        </TextBlock>
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ListViewItem>
```

And the View Model (Message is a property with INPC):

`#region Public Methods`

`public void TestPublicMethod()`
`{`
    `Message = "You have just invoked a public method !!!.";`
`}`

`#endregion`
Where:

```
xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

Apologies for poor formatting but the editor doesn't want to work on monday mornings :-p.
Because the `TextBlock` will use only the minimal space required you could use this dirty trick to get it to stretch to the width of the Column Header:

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GridViewColumnHeader}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately: *The type `EventTrigger` does not support direct content*. Additionally: Did you forget the `Text="{Binding}"` on purpose? And the `TextBlock` does not get stretched all over the column, so clicking it might be a bit challenging :)